# DB schema for single player web RPG

Tags: mysql, database, schema

I'm creating a web rpg and want to save user stats in a MYSQL database.

I've created a table called `users`. Do I put their stats in that same table? Meaning, `users` table has columns `playername`, `password`, `score`, `number of item a`, `number of item b`. Or should I separate stats into a its own table `stats`, and relate the user id to the stats?

EDIT:

Is this how I would manage stats per user?

[image]

Comment: Use a separate stats table with user ids.

Comment: @JohnMcMahon and set it up as a relational db?

Comment: Sure, MySQL is a relational database and if you want to go this route it makes sense to break up the different entities of the game into separate tables. There are a ton of different ways to implement your database, both relational and non-relational, splitting data up into different tables or not, it's all up to you and knowing your data. If you decide to model your data with a relational database then you might find it helpful to read about normalization.

Comment: @JohnMcMahon thanks. I've added a planned schema image. Does that look about right?

Answer (score 1):

If stats has a single value by user, you should add it as another column in the users table.

If there are several stats values by user, you should create another table and add a column for the user id as a foreign key.

see http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3906761/Cardinality-in-MySQL-Data-Modeling.htm

UPDATE: complementing due to your edit.

if you want to keep track of different moments when a user had different levels and experiences in your game, yes. But if the idea is to keep just the current level and experience for each player, then no - they should be columns in the user table.